# How to inspect ssl.SSLContext() configuration, e.g. ALPN protocols

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-3.11

I want to configure an [SSLContext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts) correctly.  Some settings can be checked with methods, e.g. [get_ciphers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.get_ciphers).  Others, such as those set by [set_alpn_protocols()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_alpn_protocols), don't seem to have corresponding get methods.  How do I check such settings?

I've tried using [inspect.getmembers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers), but I don't see any attributes that store the `list` of ALPN protocol `str`s.  If it helps, the source code for [set_alpn_protocols()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ssl.py#L504) seems to involve an underlying [C function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_ssl.c#L3320), but I'm not terribly familiar with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter is not exposed in the python API, which is a recurrent theme with python's wrapper around OpenSSL in general. To do this, you'll have to monkey-patch the `SSLContext.set_alpn_protocols` method to store the provided alpn protocols in an instance attribute (or some other place). That way, you can access it from some other part of your application. Example:

```
from functools import wraps
from ssl import SSLContext, create_default_context

def wrapper(set_alpn_protocols):
    """
    Wrapper designed for SSLContext.set_alpn_protocols
    """
    @wraps(set_alpn_protocols)
    def new_setter(self, alpn_protocols):
        set_alpn_protocols(self, alpn_protocols)  # This has no return value
        self._alpn_protocols = alpn_protocols  # You can change the attr name if you want

    return new_setter


SSLContext.set_alpn_protocols = wrapper(SSLContext.set_alpn_protocols)
context = create_default_context()
context.set_alpn_protocols(['h2', 'http/1.1'])

# Now if the setter was ever used, you can access it through _alpn_protocols attribute
try:
    print(context._alpn_protocols)
except AttributeError:
    print('setter was not called')
```

Output

```
['h2', 'http/1.1']
```